# why valgrind says there is only one alloc if I use 2 ints?

Tags: int, valgrind

It's the first time I use a tool to manage my program and I wanted to understand how it works with some simple tries:

```
int main(){
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);

}
```

and after execution valgrind said there was 1 alloc, 1 free which is ok.
Then i did this:

```
int main(){
int a,b;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
}
```

and after execution valgrind still says 1 alloc, 1 free. Why? didn't I allocate memory 2 times, putting 2 ints in my program? I expected it to say 2 allocs 2 free

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory at all.

Comment: yeah I didn't use any malloc but why it says 1 alloc then? Shouldn't  it be zero?

Comment: @wattbatt The runtime might allocate things internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlagrind keeps track of all memory allocations (including the ones made by a C library).

Standard I/O implementations (such as `scanf` and `printf`) will allocate buffers for internal use, which is probably what you’re seeing.

Comment: i did another little test and apparently if I put many scanf in my program the allocation is still one, could it be because every scanf uses the same allocated memory?

Comment: @wattbatt Yes, most likely it’s using the same buffer.